# How to date convert from 2015-07-03 18:30:00 +0000 to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' format in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker and I am getting the selected date from it in 2015-07-03 18:30:00 +0000 format.Now I want to convert it to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' format. How can i do it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an `NSDate` object from `UIDatePicker`. `NSDate` objects have no format, they simply represent a date/time. To obtain a formatted string from an `NSDate`, you'll need to use an `NSDateFormatter`.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dateformat yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' using datefromatter in Objective C

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
    NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:YOUR_DATE_TO_CONVERT];
```

and Swift

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
var string = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(YOUR_DATE_TO_CONVERT)
```

Enjoy coding!